# Mask overscroll effect for round corners

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-overscoll

How to mask overscroll effect for round corners in ViewPager?

Thank you for help.

[android overscroll effect problem - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FZ3e.png)

```
<!--corner.xml set as background in ViewPager-->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="90dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I've had this problem before and found it was only happening in the emulator, have you tried it on an actual phone yet? It is such a bizarre thing, if I remember right it didn't happen on a 2nd computer I tried it on either. It's entirely possible you stumbled upon a similar but different issue though...

Comment: @AdamWilliamLarson Yes, I have tried it on 2 others actual phones and I have unfortunately the same issue :(